# #address-cells and #size-cells field in device tree overlay range property

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, fpga, intel-fpga, device-tree

I am trying to load a file into a stratix10 FPGA and map the FPGA busses using the embedded Hard processor, ARM running linux

`(Linux  5.4.23-03466-gcc83036e6a78 #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Aug 5 10:15:00 CEST 2020 aarch64 GNU/Linux).`

This is done with device tree overlays.

The main device tree contains: (where [...] indicates removed section of -hopefully- no interrest)

```
#include "socfpga_stratix10.dtsi"

/ {
   [...]
       soc {
                clocks {
                        osc1 {
                                clock-frequency = <25000000>;
                        };
                };

                eccmgr {
                        sdmmca-ecc@ff8c8c00 {
                                compatible = "altr,socfpga-s10-sdmmc-ecc",
                                             "altr,socfpga-sdmmc-ecc";
                                reg = <0xff8c8c00 0x100>;
                                altr,ecc-parent = <&mmc>;
                                interrupts = <14 4>,
                                             <15 4>;
                        };
                };
        };
};
```

The included file, `socfpga_stratix10.dtsi` contains:

```
/{
        soc {
                #address-cells = <1>;
                #size-cells = <1>;
                compatible = "simple-bus";
                device_type = "soc";
                interrupt-parent = <&intc>;
                ranges = <0 0 0 0xffffffff>;

                base_fpga_region {
                        #address-cells = <0x1>;
                        #size-cells = <0x1>;

                        compatible = "fpga-region";
                        fpga-mgr = <&fpga_mgr>;
                };
        [...]
        };
[...]
};
```

Note that fields `#address-cells` and `#size-cells` are set to `<1>` in both the parent (`/soc`) and child(`/soc/base_fpga_region`) nodes.
My initial try for the device tree overlay hence looked like this:

```
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;
/ {
        fragment@1 {
                target-path = "/soc/base_fpga_region";
                __overlay__ {
                        firmware-name = "fpga_image.rbf";
                        config-complete-timeout-us = <3000000>;
                        #address-cells = <1>;                           /* address in the child (fpga region) space are given as 1 U32 values */
                        #size-cells = <1>;                              /* sizes   in the child (fpga region) space are given as 1 U32 values */
                                                                        /* mapping from ARM address to FPGA addresses: */
                                                                        /* see https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/programmable/hps/stratix-10/hps.html */
                        ranges = <0x00000000 0x80000000 0x40000000>,    /* hps to FPGA mapping: address 0 of the child bus mapps to address 80000000 in the parent space: length 0x40000 */
                                 <0x00000000 0xf9000000 0x00200000>;    /* lightweight hps to FPGA mapping: 0 maps to parent f9000000. length 1000 */
                };
        };
};
```

But when I compile this device tree, I get:

```
arch/arm64/boot/dts/altera/socfpga_stratix10_ovl_load.dts:13.4-14.41: Warning (ranges_format): /fragment@1/__overlay__:ranges: "ranges" property has invalid length (24 bytes) (parent #address-cells == 2, child #address-cells == 1, #size-cells == 1)
arch/arm64/boot/dts/altera/socfpga_stratix10_ovl_load.dts:6.15-15.5: Warning (avoid_default_addr_size): /fragment@1/__overlay__: Relying on default #address-cells value
arch/arm64/boot/dts/altera/socfpga_stratix10_ovl_load.dts:6.15-15.5: Warning (avoid_default_addr_size): /fragment@1/__overlay__: Relying on default #size-cells value
```

OK... after all, the compiler maybe does not know much about the parent node `/soc` when compiling my overlay, and takes default values for `#address-cells` and `#size-cells`...
So I added a little reminder in my overlay as follows:

```
dts-v1/;
/plugin/;
/ {
        fragment@0 {
                target-path = "/soc";
                __overlay__ {
                        #address-cells = <1>;                           /* */
                        #size-cells = <1>;                              /* */
                };
        };

        fragment@1 {
                target-path = "/soc/base_fpga_region";
                __overlay__ {
                        firmware-name = "fpga_image.rbf";
                        config-complete-timeout-us = <3000000>;
                        #address-cells = <1>;                           /* address in the child (fpga region) space are given as 1 U32 values */
                        #size-cells = <1>;                              /* sizes   in the child (fpga region) space are given as 1 U32 values */
                                                                        /* mapping from ARM address to FPGA addresses: */
                                                                        /* see https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/programmable/hps/stratix-10/hps.html */
                        ranges = <0x00000000 0x80000000 0x40000000>,    /* hps to FPGA mapping: address 0 of the child bus mapps to address 80000000 in the parent space: length 0x40000 */
                                 <0x00000000 0xf9000000 0x00200000>;    /* lightweight hps to FPGA mapping: 0 maps to parent f9000000. length 1000 */
                };
        };
};
```

But that did not do any difference! I still get:

```
arch/arm64/boot/dts/altera/socfpga_stratix10_ovl_load.dts:21.4-22.41: Warning (ranges_format): /fragment@1/__overlay__:ranges: "ranges" property has invalid length (24 bytes) (parent #address-cells == 2, child #address-cells == 1, #size-cells == 1)
arch/arm64/boot/dts/altera/socfpga_stratix10_ovl_load.dts:14.15-23.5: Warning (avoid_default_addr_size): /fragment@1/__overlay__: Relying on default #address-cells value
arch/arm64/boot/dts/altera/socfpga_stratix10_ovl_load.dts:14.15-23.5: Warning (avoid_default_addr_size): /fragment@1/__overlay__: Relying on default #size-cells value
```

That confuses me a bit: the `#address-cells` of the parent `/soc` node is now clearly specified (twice: once in the original device-tree and once in the overlay)...

What is going on? what am I doing wrong?

In desperation I also tried (note the extra zero for the parent adress in the range spec):

```
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;
/ {
        fragment@1 {
                target-path = "/soc/base_fpga_region";
                __overlay__ {
                        firmware-name = "fpga_image.rbf";
                        config-complete-timeout-us = <3000000>;
                        #address-cells = <1>;                           /* address in the child (fpga region) space are given as 1 U32 values */
                        #size-cells = <1>;                              /* sizes   in the child (fpga region) space are given as 1 U32 values */
                                                                        /* mapping from ARM address to FPGA addresses: */
                                                                        /* see https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/programmable/hps/stratix-10/hps.html */
                        ranges = <0x00000000 0 0x80000000 0x40000000>,  /* hps to FPGA mapping: address 0 of the child bus mapps to address 80000000 in the parent space: length 0x40000 */
                                 <0x00000000 0 0xf9000000 0x00200000>;  /* lightweight hps to FPGA mapping: 0 maps to parent f9000000. length 1000 */
                };
        };
};
```

which compiles with the usual warning:

```
arch/arm64/boot/dts/altera/socfpga_stratix10_ovl_load.dts:6.15-15.5: Warning (avoid_default_addr_size): /fragment@1/__overlay__: Relying on default #address-cells value
arch/arm64/boot/dts/altera/socfpga_stratix10_ovl_load.dts:6.15-15.5: Warning (avoid_default_addr_size): /fragment@1/__overlay__: Relying on default #size-cells value
```

But when I apply my overlay and try to access something in the mapped region (e.g. at address 0xF9000000 for the light weight bus), it result in a `Bus Error`... Which possibly tells me that even this was not done as I wished...

The device tree specification says:

> The child-bus-addressis a physical address within the child bus
> address space. The number of cells to represent the address is bus
> dependent and can be determined from the #address-cells of this node
> (the node in which the ranges property appears)

> The parent-bus-address
> is a physical address within the parent bus address space. The number
> of cells to represent the parent address is bus dependent and can be
> determined from the #address-cellsproperty of the node that defines
> the parent’s address space.

> The length specifies the size of the range
> in the child’s address space. The number of cells to represent the
> size can be determined from the #size-cellsof this node (the node in
> which the rangesproperty appears).

From this, I don't understand why my first, or at least second attempt failed.
When it comes to the third desperate attempt, I am not sure what gets done, but comments are appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: size-cells doesn't inherit from the parent neccessarily, it depends on the number of addresses: you have two there, so it should be #size-cells = <2>; surely ?

Comment: The compiler says there is a <2> somewhere, but I don't see where this comes from... I have <1> everywhere in my dts/dtsi files, haven't I?

Comment: where you have  ranges = <0x00000000 0 0x80000000 0x40000000>,                              <0x00000000 0 0xf9000000 0x00200000>; thats two

Comment: I mean, you quote it yourself: The length specifies the size of the range in the child’s address space.

Comment: So I would try #address-cells = <2>;/
                        #size-cells = <1>; but these things are very tricky sometimes ;)

Comment: I did try 4 cells indeed as a last try ( <0x00000000 0 0x80000000 0x40000000>) because the compilers kept telling me it beleives the parent node has address-cells set to <2> (the default), despite all my statements it is <1>! This range statemenet does not set the number of cell: it is is simply using the number of cell (which I expected to be <1> but the compiler has set has <2> for a reason I'd like to understand)

Comment: Also note that I have specified both the parent (/soc) and child size to 1, so I cannot see any inheritance taking place here, not either way the device tree compiler would use any default values as all are specified to 1